# How to read the email Sent folder by Microsoft Graph correctly?

Tags: json, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to read my email **Sent** folder.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('outbox')/messages
```

in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), I always get a empty array:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('16f5a7b6-5a15-4568-aa5a-31bb117e9967')/mailFolders('outbox')/messages",
    "value": []
}
```

And when I run

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders
```

Only Sent folder (Outbox) shows 0 email, but actually there are emails in the folder.

How can I read **Sent** folder correctly? Thanks

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('576552d5-3bc0-42a6-a53d-bfceb405db23')/mailFolders",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders?$skip=10",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgAuAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhAQCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAHurthAAA=",
            "displayName": "Archive",
            "parentFolderId": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgAuAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhAQCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEIAAA=",
            "childFolderCount": 0,
            "unreadItemCount": 0,
            "totalItemCount": 3510
        },
        {
            "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgAuAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhAQCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEMAAA=",
            "displayName": "Inbox",
            "parentFolderId": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgAuAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhAQCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEIAAA=",
            "childFolderCount": 5,
            "unreadItemCount": 1,
            "totalItemCount": 44
        },
        {
            "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgAuAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhAQCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAELAAA=",
            "displayName": "Outbox",
            "parentFolderId": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgAuAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhAQCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEIAAA=",
            "childFolderCount": 0,
            "unreadItemCount": 0,
            "totalItemCount": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outbox is not Sent Items. I would expect Outbox to have 0 messages in it almost always, since Outbox only holds messages as they are being sent, so messages only reside there for a very short time.

To get Sent Items, use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems`.